# Returning array as Observable to Behavior subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular6

I am applying todo filters in angular 6 with routing based on if todo is completed only completed(checked) todos should display on clicking completed link.
I managed to get todos that are completed in todoService (getTodos) function.
But as getTodos is Observable it was not allowing me to return me to todos array

Here is my code for service

```
  public getTodos(query = ''): Observable<Todo[]>{
    if(query === 'completed' || query === 'active'){
      const isCompleted = query === 'completed';
      let todos = this.allTodos.filter(todo => todo.completed === isCompleted);
      console.log(todos);
      // this.storageService.getTodos().subscribe(todos => this.allTodos.filter(todo => todo.completed === isCompleted));
      // return this.todos.next('todos');
      return this.todos.asObservable();
    }else{
      return this.todos.asObservable();
    }
  }
```

Full Link of project in stackblitz

[Project link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxjnyh)

PS: I am new to angular and still learning Observables/rxjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `BehaviorSubject` in your Service. You can just add a public `Observable` to your service:

```
public todos$: Observable<Todo[]> = this.todos.asObservable();
```

And then in your `getTodos` method:

```
public getTodos(query = ''): Observable < Todo[] > {
  if (query === 'completed' || query === 'active') {
    ...
    this.todos.next(todos);
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
}
```

And in your Component, you can get the `todos` by `subscribe` to this `Observable` using this:

```
todos;
constructor(private todoService: TodoService, ...) {}
...
this.todoService.todos$.subscribe(todos => this.todos = todos);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support 
Can you please fork in stackblitz so that i can understand it well. @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 0):

```
    Todo[] myTodos;

    todoService.getTodos('').subscribe(response => {
        //here you can response - what you return from service
        this.myTodos=response;
    });
```

response is sothmething what you return form service